# Is there a way to reset this countdown timer (composed in HTML & CSS) by clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a five sec. countdown timer that I want to reset through the *onclick* function. I want to click on the timer itself – NOT a separate button – to achieve this effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="countdown" onclick="myFunction()"> \\stuck on writing an animation-reset script for “myFunction()\\
  <svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" stroke-width="10">
    <circle r="45"></circle>
    <circle r="45" stroke-dasharray="282.7433388230814" stroke-dashoffset="282.7433388230814px"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
<style>
.countdown {
  display: grid;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  float: center;
}
.countdown::after {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  place-self: center;
  font: 1em/2 ubuntu mono, consolas, monaco, monospace;
  animation: num 5s steps(1);
  content: "0:" counter(s, decimal-leading-zero);
}

@keyframes num {
  0% {
    counter-reset: s 5;
  }
  20% {
    counter-reset: s 4;
  }
  40% {
    counter-reset: s 3;
  }
  60% {
    counter-reset: s 2;
  }
  80% {
    counter-reset: s 1;
  }
  100% {
    counter-reset: s 0;
  }
}
svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

[r] {
  fill: none;
  stroke: silver;
}
[r] + [r] {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #8A9B0F;
  animation: arc 5s linear;
  animation-name: arc, col;
}

@keyframes arc {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes col {
  0% {
    stroke: #00ff00;
  }
  25% {
    stroke: #bfff00;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: #ffff00;
  }
  75% {
    stroke: #ff8000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: #ff0000;
  }
}
</style>
```

Being a programming n00b, I hacked together this setup by copying, pasting, and modifying snippets of code I found online.

Now, however, I’ve reached a point where I’m having a hard time intuiting a solution to my issue (probably due to the inclusion of animations and keyframes for some nice graphical effects.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. You have multiple animations running: num, arc, and col. When you click the countdown, we can loop through all the animations in the document. We can cancel them and play them again. This will have the reset effect that you want. Here is the code:

```
<script>
    //get animations when page loads
    let animations = document.getAnimations();
    let num = animations[0];
    let arc = animations[1];
    let col = animations[2];
  function myFunction() {
    //restart all animations

    num.cancel();
    num.play();

    arc.cancel();
    arc.play();

    col.cancel();
    col.play();        
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. 

That worked UNTIL the timer hit 0. After reaching 0 it won’t reset no matter how many times I click it. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I fixed the code and it works when the timer hits 0. Please let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: Almost. With that new code the timer actually resets at 4 (i.e. countdown begins at 4) after hitting 0. The arc, though, continues to complete its rotation in 5 seconds. I got them to sync by setting “let col = animations[2];” to [0], but then the color of the arc stopped resetting.

Comment: That's strange. For mine it works fine. It resets at 5. Maybe you can try to change the order the methods are called. E.g. num.cancel() arc.cancel() col.cancel(), num.play() etc. Try and see if that works.

Comment: Nope. Same problem — the timer resets at 4 (it actually displays zero for 1 sec. before reverting to 4, 3, 2…).

Comment: I also noticed that I can click **twice** to reset it at **5** AFTER it’s reached 0. Clicking **once** BEFORE it reaches 0 has the same effect. BUT clicking **only once** after it’s reached 0 resets it at 4 (again, after displaying **0 instead of 5** for 1 sec.)

Comment: I’ve replicated my experience here: https://codepen.io/Cheema11229/pen/dyjVLmr